# Jenkins is not picking up Environment variable to be used in windows batch script

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, batch-file, visual-c++, jenkins

I am building a visual studio solution containing number of project. I wanted to disable multiprocess build, so , i tried setting an enviroment variable CL to /MP1. But it didn't worked in Jenkins while working in running the batch script for building solution using command line.

Answer (score 1):

Good morning,

Log to your Jenkins server, and stop the Jenkins from the command line. While doing this, open your web-browser and refresh the Jenkins webpage to make sure it stopped(it will take around 5 seconds to stop the service). Then start again from the command line, it will update the variable. I did yesterday, to run my unit tests. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

To set environment variables for individual projects, use the checkbox 'Prepare an environment for the run' and set what environment variables you want in the format 'ENV=value' in the Properties content box.

Otherwise, all I can suggest is that you haven;t restarted the Jenkins service after setting your variable in Windows.

Comment: I had done the Jenkins restart(even  system(windows) restart also). I will try your suggested approach. Thanks.

Comment: and make sure you set the env var in the system's section, not the user's of the control panel applet.

Comment: I did what you suggested above, but still the batch script which is using visual studio "devenv.exe" is not picking up enviroment variables as it is supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

You can also used the EnvInject plugin, it works well.
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin

Comment: I am using this plugin and setting the ENV variable after SCM update. But batch file is not using these variable which when run through cmd.exe is working fine.